# What's 'reservation' in RISC-V's 'lr' instruction?

Tags: atomic, cpu-architecture, riscv, memory-barriers, load-link-store-conditional

From `8.2 Load-Reserved/Store-Conditional Instructions` chapter in RISC-V's unprivileged ISA Manual,

> LR.W loads a word from the address in rs1, places the sign-extended value in rd, and registers a reservation set—a set of bytes that subsumes the bytes in the addressed word. SC.W conditionally writes a word in rs2 to the address in rs1: the SC.W succeeds only if the reservation is still valid and the reservation set contains the bytes being written.

What's the `reservation` in the description? How is it implemented in hardware? How does a Hart know if the reservation has been invalidated by another Hart?

Comment: Presumably it notices if the cache line leaves exclusively-owned state between the LL and the SC.  As far as software is concerned, it's an LL/SC like on MIPS, ARM, PowerPC, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional even mentions "load reserved" as a synonym.  SO actually has a tag for that, although IDK if any specifically ask how the hardware works, e.g. ARM's "monitor" region.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/load-link-store-conditional

Comment: @PeterCordes So `reservation` can be viewed as a flag maintained by hardware. Maybe CPU can monitor changes on the same address accessed by `lr` through cache line or some other hardware components if there's no cache. That's fine for me as I'm a software guy. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the reservation is like a flag: look at the operation of the `SC` instruction: it is conditional AND it tells you if it worked or not, with an boolean output of the result going to `rd`.  If it didn't work, you can retry with a short spin loop.